# mysql - get data from another tabel according to search?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables that use the same ID as PK  , 
I have make a "where" question in table2 and got a resault

now I wnat to use the ID I got and see what is the Name from table 1

```
table 1 (Users) is 

ID Name 
1 David
2 Guy
3 Robert 
4 Helen 

table 2 (history_Users_daily )is 

ID ADDED_Money User_Date
1   0          2019-02-07
1   1          2019-02-08
1   0          2019-02-10
2   0          2019-02-07
2   0          2019-02-13
3   5          2019-02-12
4   0          2019-02-12
4   0          2019-02-13
```

this is the what I did on table 2:

```
SELECT ID,SUM(ADDED_Money)  AS Total_Money_7_Days
from 
v7.history_Users_daily 
where ( com_id = '1' and User_DATE >= date(curdate() - 7)  )
GROUP BY ID
HAVING Total_Money_7_Days < '2'
order by Total_Money_7_Days ;
```

when I run this I see all the ID that have less then 2

this is the result I'm getting :

```
 ID Total_Money_7_Days
 1  1
 2  0
 4  0
```

now I want to see what is the Name of each ID according to table 1

so in the final I will get this :

```
ID Name Total_Money_7_Days
1  David 1
2  Guy   0
4  Helen 0
```

I have try all kinds of "Join"(examples I have found on google, but none of them work )

what I need to do?

Thanks ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `JOIN` directly to the `Users` table:

```
SELECT h.ID, u.Name, SUM(h.ADDED_Money)  AS Total_Money_7_Days
FROM history_Users_daily h
JOIN Users u ON u.ID = h.ID
WHERE ( com_id = '1' AND User_DATE >= date(curdate() - 7)  )
GROUP BY h.ID, u.Name
HAVING Total_Money_7_Days < '2'
ORDER BY Total_Money_7_Days DESC
```

Output

```
ID  Name    Total_Money_7_Days
1   David   1
2   Guy     0
4   Helen   0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bAuosLq4ZEe6YnfJmvnMGW/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
select t2.Id, t1.Name, t2.Total_Money_7_Days
from users t1
Join (SELECT ID,SUM(ADDED_Money)  AS Total_Money_7_Days
     from 
     v7.history_Users_daily 
     where ( com_id = '1' and User_DATE >= date(curdate() - 7)  )
     GROUP BY ID
     HAVING Total_Money_7_Days < '2'
     order by Total_Money_7_Days
     ) t2
on t2.Id = t1.Id
```